# Wordpress / PHP - Do a single shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

In WP you can filter shortcodes from a string and execute their hooked functions with `do_shortcode($string)`.

Is it possible to filter a single shortcode, instead of all registered shortcodes?

for example I need a few shortcodes to be available for comment posters as well, but not all for obvious reasons :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function do_shortcode_by_tags($content, $tags)
{
    global $shortcode_tags;
    $_tags = $shortcode_tags; // store temp copy
    foreach ($_tags as $tag => $callback) {
        if (!in_array($tag, $tags)) // filter unwanted shortcode
            unset($shortcode_tags[$tag]);
    }

    $shortcoded = do_shortcode($content);
    $shortcode_tags = $_tags; // put all shortcode back
    return $shortcoded;
}
```

This works by filtering the global `$shortcode_tags`, running `do_shortcode()`, then putting everything back as it was before.

Example use;

```
$comment = do_shortcode_by_tags($comment, array('tag_1', 'tag_2'));
```

This will apply the shortcode `tag_1` and `tag_2` to the comment.